# Delete unwanted arrays from multidimensional array

Tags: php, arrays, wordpress, multidimensional-array

I am creating a WooCommerce plugin, which detects duplicate guest orders based on date and email address. I was able to create an array, where are all data which i need. If there is a duplicate the order id is added to the correct email address.

But now I want to delete all the arrays where are only 1 order id present.

CODE:

```
$i = 0;

$big_order = array();

foreach($order_ids as $id) {

    $order = new WC_Order($id);

    //print_r ($order);

    if(array_search($order->billing_email, array_column($big_order, 'email')) !== false){
        $key = array_search($order->billing_email, array_column($big_order, 'email'));
        $big_order['row-'.$key]['order_id'][] = $id;
    } else {
        $big_order['row-'.$i]['email'] = $order->billing_email;
        $big_order['row-'.$i]['order_id'][] = $id;
    }

    $i++;

}

print_r ($big_order);
```

OUTPUT:

```
Array
(
[row-0] => Array
    (
        [email] => alma@alma.hu
        [order_id] => Array
            (
                [0] => 14
            )

    )

[row-1] => Array
    (
        [email] => peter18.xxxx@gmail.com
        [order_id] => Array
            (
                [0] => 13
            )

    )

[row-2] => Array
    (
        [email] => peter.xxxx@outlook.com
        [order_id] => Array
            (
                [0] => 12
                [1] => 10
            )

    )

)
```

In this case I only need row-2 array.
Thanks for the help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use `array_filter()` and `count()`:

```
$big_order = array_filter($big_order, function (array $row) {
    return 1 < count($row['order_id']);
});
```

For reference, see:

- http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-filter.php
- http://php.net/manual/en/function.count.php

Comment: Thanks, I have found an another method with help array and count :). But your solution is more elegant :). $new_array = array();
 foreach($big_order as $item)
 {
  //echo count($item['order_id']); 
  if(count($item['order_id']) > 1)
  {
   $new_array[] = $item;
  }
 }

Comment: @beamkiller There're always different possibilities to solve a problem, hehe!